# How to keep sticky checkboxes from resetting when submitting? (Multiple forms on one page)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I am using dreamweaver and have two forms on a page that each submit to the same mySQL database, but different rows, using php.They each have "sticky" code to keep them from losing values when I submit the data to mySQL. The problem is form1 loses the values when I submit form2 and vice-versa. Two full days and driving me nuts.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/pmpConn.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}



$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form2")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE readiness_one_day SET on_time=%s WHERE ready_primary=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['on_time2']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ready_primary2'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_pmpConn, $pmpConn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $pmpConn) or die(mysql_error());

}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE readiness_one_day SET on_time=%s WHERE ready_primary=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['on_time1']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ready_primary1'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_pmpConn, $pmpConn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $pmpConn) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
  <p>
    <input name="ready_primary1" type="text" id="ready_primary1" value="1" size="2" maxlength="2" readonly="readonly" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="on_time1" type="checkbox" id="on_time1" value="1"<?php if (isset($_POST['on_time1']) && ($_POST['on_time1'] == '1')) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?> /> <!code for sticky checkboxes>
    <label for="on_time1">On Time</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="Update" />
  </p>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
</form>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" >
  <p>
    <input name="ready_primary2" type="text" id="ready_primary2" value="2" size="2" maxlength="2" readonly="readonly" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="on_time2" type="checkbox" id="on_time2" value="1" <?php if (isset($_POST['on_time2']) && ($_POST['on_time2'] == '1')) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?> /> <!code for sticky checkboxes>
    <label for="on_time2">On Time</label>
  </p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Update" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form2" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `$_SESSION` variables right after each form is submitted, so you can persist the values between pages. After that, you can do something like this:

On the form submitted page:

```
<?php 
   session_start(); 
   $SESSION['one_box'] = True;
?>
```

On the page with the form:

```
<?php 
start_session(); 
function selected($value) {
   if (isset($_SESSION[$value]) {
      return "checked='yes'";
   }
   else {
      return "";
   }
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="one_box" <?php echo selected("one_box"); ?> />
```

Comment: Or with POSTED data `echo($_POST && isset($_POST['one_box']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '');`

Comment: Only reason I didn't do that, is because he said he has a second form that gets submitted as well.

Comment: Thank you David,there is only one page. when data is submitted it returns to the same page.I understand where to enter the checkbox code. 1.But where (in my code) should I submit the first two blocks of code. 2. Should session_start() and start_session() be the same?

Comment: David, can you please clarify further.